# How to access MongoDB atlas through https API?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, mongodb-atlas

Since I've been migrated to **Mongodb Atlas** I got an **cors error**.

The only URL I found on my mongodb dashboard was `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.cnh0m.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase`

Here is my code :

```
getClap = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`mongodb+srv://...`)
        console.log(res.data);
    } catch (err) console.error(err);
};
```

Is there any way to connect mongodb directly with axios like before with mlab ? Using an HTTPS address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer reading the mlab documentation.

> **Q. Does Atlas have a Data API?**
>
> If you are using the mLab Data API note that MongoDB Atlas does not
> have a data API. However, we have open-sourced the mLab Data API and
> made it easy for you to self-host the mLab Data API on Heroku.
>
> Once you have re-configured your application to use your self-hosted
> mLab Data API, you’ll be able to migrate your mLab-hosted deployments
> to MongoDB Atlas.

[source link](https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas/#data-api)